# Como alterar o layout do ReplyKeyboardMarkup/Quick Reply no api.ai para o Telegram?

Tags: chatbot, telegram, telegram-bot

ai para criação de um bot, ao utilizar o quick reply do serviço o layout do teclado (ReplyKeyboardMarkup) no Telegram fica vertical, cortando assim todas as mensagens:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vi que na [documentação](https://core.telegram.org/bots#keyboards) dos bot do Telegram há a opção de você customizar esse layout. Como isso pode ser feito no api.ai?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui, pra fazer isso tive que deixar de usar o Quick Reply e usei o [Custom Payload](https://docs.api.ai/docs/rich-messages#custom-payload) que permite você informar o json de resposta customizado tal como na documentação da plataforma que você está usando. Como no meu caso é o Telegram ficou assim:

```
  "telegram": {
    "text": "Algumas coisa que posso fazer:",
    "reply_markup": {
      "resize_keyboard": true, "one_time_keyboard": true, 
      "keyboard": [
        ["abrir chamado"],
        ["buscar contracheque"],
        ["consultar avaliações"],
        ["o que mais você pode fazer?"]
        ]

    }
  },
```

Resultado foi bem o que eu esperava:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fica ai a dica para os próximos que passarem por esse problema de ter que customizar o teclado do Telegram pelo api.ai.